# Time Tracker using JSON

Tags: python, json

This is a simple command line interface program that just keeps track of duration spent on multiple tasks.

Any areas of improvements are welcomed to be pointed out.

````
import json
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime
td = datetime.timedelta


def encode_time(t):
    if isinstance(t, dt):
        return {
            '_type': 'datetime',
            'year': t.year,
            'month': t.month,
            'day': t.day,
            'hour': t.hour,
            'minute': t.minute,
            'second': t.second
        }
    elif isinstance(t, td):
        return {
            '_type': 'timedelta',
            'days': t.days,
            'seconds': t.seconds,
            'microseconds': t.microseconds
        }
    return t


def decode_time(t):
    if '_type' in t:

        data_type = t['_type']
        del t['_type']

        if data_type == 'datetime':
            return dt(**t)
        elif data_type == 'timedelta':
            return td(**t)
    return t


def display_pending():
    """
    pretty prints the pending dictionary.

    :return: None
    """
    print('\n')
    if pending:
        max_len = max([len(key) for key in pending.keys()])
        print('Pending Activities:')
        print('-'*40)
    else:
        max_len = 0
        print('No pending data.')

    counter = 0
    for key, value in pending.items():
        duration_so_far = (dt.now() - value)

        seconds = duration_so_far.seconds
        days = duration_so_far.days
        hours = seconds // 3600
        minutes = (seconds // 60) % 60

        s = 's' if days > 1 else ''
        days = f'{days} Day{s} ' if days > 0 else ''

        s = 's' if hours > 1 else ''
        hours = f'{hours} Hour{s} ' if hours > 0 else ''

        s = 's' if minutes > 1 else ''
        minutes = f'{minutes} Min{s} ' if minutes > 0 else ''

        seconds = f'{seconds} Seconds' if seconds < 60 else ''

        print(f'[{counter}] {key.capitalize():{max_len}} | {value}')  # Key and start time.

        max_len += 4  # Adding 4 to max_len to make sure this line is aligned with the one above it.
        print(f'{"." * max_len:{max_len}} | {days}{hours}{minutes}{seconds}\n')  # Duration so far.
        print('-' * 40)
        max_len -= 4  # Avoiding mutating max_len.
        counter += 1


def display_durations():
    """
    Pretty prints the durations dictionary.

    :return: None
    """
    print('\n')
    counter = 0

    if durations:
        max_len = max([len(key) for key in durations.keys()])
        print('Durations: ')
        print('_' * 40)
    else:
        max_len = 0
        print('No durations data')

    for key, value in durations.items():
        print(f'[{counter}] {key.capitalize():{max_len}}  | {value}')
        print('-' * 40)
        counter += 1


pending = {}
durations = {}

# Reading data from pending.json
try:
    with open('pending.json', 'r') as pending_json:
        pending = json.load(pending_json, object_hook=decode_time)
        s = 's' if len(pending) > 1 else ''
        print(f'{len(pending)} pending item{s} loaded from disk')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('  "pending.json" was not found, creating.')
    open('pending.json', 'x').close()
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('pending.json is empty...')

# Reading data from durations.json
try:
    with open('durations.json', 'r') as durations_json:
        durations = json.load(durations_json, object_hook=decode_time)
        s = 's' if len(durations) > 1 else ''
        print(f'{len(durations)} duration item{s} loaded from disk')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('  "durations.json" was not found, creating.')
    open('durations.json', 'x').close()
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print('durations.json is empty...')

if pending:
    display_pending()
if durations:
    display_durations()

# Acquiring user input.
while True:

    activity = input('\n>>> ').lower()

    now = dt.now()
    start_time = pending.get(activity, None)

    if activity == 'quit':
        print('Exiting.')

        break
    elif activity == '':
        continue

    if activity in pending:
        duration = now - start_time
        print(f'"{activity}" ended. Duration: {duration}')
        durations[activity] = durations.get(activity, td(0)) + duration  # Record duration of activity.
        del pending[activity]  # Delete activity from pending list to confirm that it's completed.

        continue

    elif activity == 'man':
        activity = input('Activity Name: ')
        activity_duration = {}

        # Get num of days, hours, etc.. of manually eneterd activity.
        for parameter in ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', 'microseconds']:
            while True:
                i = input(f'{parameter.capitalize()}: ')
                if i.isnumeric():
                    activity_duration[parameter] = int(i)
                    break
                elif i == '':
                    activity_duration[parameter] = 0
                    break

        add_minus = input('Add / Minus: ').lower()

        if add_minus == 'add':
            durations[activity] = durations.get(activity, td(0)) + td(**activity_duration)
        elif add_minus == 'minus':
            durations[activity] = durations.get(activity, td(0)) - td(**activity_duration)

        display_durations()

        continue

    elif activity == 'del':

        activity = input('Delete: ')

        if activity == 'all':
            confirmed = input('Delete Everything? y/n ')
            if confirmed == 'y':
                pending.clear()
                durations.clear()
                print('Data Cleared.')
                continue

        key_index = [[None, None]]  # A list of index, key pairs for each key in pending or durations dictionaries.

        # If the activity the user wants to delete is a number, treat it as an index,
        # Unless the activity is an entry in either pending/durations lists:
        if activity.isnumeric() and activity not in set(list(pending.keys()) + list(durations.keys())):

            is_numeric = True
            activity = int(activity)
            wanted_list = input('Delete From Pending/Durations? p/d: ')

            if wanted_list == 'd':
                key_index = [(index, key) for index, key in enumerate(durations.keys())]
            elif wanted_list == 'p':
                key_index = [(index, key) for index, key in enumerate(pending.keys())]
            # If no list specified then delete from durations or pending according to index given.
            else:
                if activity <= len(durations) - 1:
                    key_index = [(index, key) for index, key in enumerate(durations.keys())]
                elif activity <= len(pending) - 1:
                    key_index = [(index, key) for index, key in enumerate(pending.keys())]

            for index, key in key_index:
                if index == activity:
                    break

            activity = key
        else:
            is_numeric = False

        if activity in pending:
            not_in_pending = False
            del pending[activity]
            print(f'"{activity.capitalize()}" deleted from pending')
        else:
            not_in_pending = True

        if activity in durations:
            not_in_durations = False
            del durations[activity]
            print(f'{activity.capitalize()} deleted from durations')
        else:
            not_in_durations = True

        if not_in_pending and not_in_durations:

            if is_numeric:
                print('No data')
            else:
                print('Key Not Found')

        continue

    elif activity == 'data':
        display_pending()
        display_durations()

        continue

    elif activity == 'help':
        print('''
Enter activity name for it to be started.
Enter the same name again for it to be ended and record it's duration.

    Commands:
        man: manually edit a duration
        del: delete an entry from pending activities and/or duration
        data: show currently pending activities and duration records

        quit: exit program and save edits.  
        ''')

        continue

    pending[activity] = now

    print(f'"{activity.capitalize()}" started on: {now}')

print('  Writing updated data to disk.')

if len(pending) > 0:
    with open('pending.json', 'w') as pending_json:
        json.dump(pending, pending_json, default=encode_time, indent=2)
else:
    # So that json doesn't dump an empty dictionary symbol: {} to the file.
    open('pending.json', 'w').close()

if len(durations) > 0:
    with open('durations.json', 'w') as durations_json:
        json.dump(durations, durations_json, default=encode_time, indent=2)
else:
    open('durations.json', 'w').close()

print('  Data updated.')

exit_confirm = input('Press Enter To Exit...')
```
````

Answer (score 2):

- Not a fan of all your single or double letter variable names. Please write out variables like `time`, `datetime` and `timedelta`.

  However I do think `s` is more readable than a written out variable name.
- I would prefer it if `decode_time` copied `t` before mutating it. This makes your code easier to use as there are no side effects.

  ```py
  t = t.copy()
  data_type = t.pop('_type')
  ```
- You can change the `if`s in `decode_time` to use a dictionary to make the code easier to extend.

  If you have more than two data types then the dictionary will allow you to reduce duplicate code.

  You can use either of the following based on your preference.

  ```py
  DECODES = {
      'datetime': datetime.datetime,
      'timedelta': datetime.timedelta,
  }
  ```

  ```py
  try:
      fn = DECODES[data_type]
  except KeyError:
      pass
  else:
      return fn(**t)
  ```

  ```py
  return DECODES.get(data_type, lambda **kwargs: kwargs)(**t)
  ```
- You kinda just gave up on seconds in `display_pending`. You've not calculated how many seconds it would need nor have you adjusted for when it's 1.

  To reduce the amount of duplication you can use a fairly simple for loop and a dictionary. We can build the dictionary with the existing code to build the variables. If we assign the values to the name to print, we can iterate over the dictionary getting all the information needed to display each unit.

  With some carefully placed assignments we can exploit the fact that dictionaries are sorted and have the same output you currently have.

  Additionally we can use a comprehension for some sugar to filter missing units.

  ```py
  duration = {'Day': duration_so_far.days}
  remainder, seconds = divmod(duration_so_far.seconds, 60)
  duration['Hour'], duration['Minute'] = divmod(remainder, 60)
  duration['Second'] = seconds

  time = ' '.join(
      f'{v} {k}{"s" if v != 1 else ""}'
      for k, v in duration.items()
      if v
  )

  ...

  print(f'{"." * max_len:{max_len}} | {time}\n')
  ```
- I would recommend toning down the amount of `print`s you have. These have side effects like deleting the type in `decode_time`. This makes your code harder to:

  - Test - now you need to wrap `sys.std.out` for basic functions.
  - Understand - others now have to second guess each and every one of your functions. This is because you've done it once and not been explicit about it, what's to stop you from doing it twice?
  - Maintain - refactoring your code to keep the same output is more challenging without a complete rewrite.

Comment: The problem with `datetime` is its alternatives. `from datetime import datetime` will be confusing, since now the `datetime` class takes the place of what is usually the `datetime` module. This leaves two sensible, as in unambiguous/clear, ways. Either `import datetime` and call `datetime.datetime` everywhere, or the somewhat [widespread short verion `from datetime import datetime as dt`](https://github.com/search?q=%22from+datetime+import+datetime+as+dt%22&type=Code). Subjective, but the latter is useful (like `np` to `numpy`).

Comment: @AlexPovel Yeah no, consistent code fixes that problem.